# A recursive function "game" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I don't quite understand the following code:

```
game :: ([Move], Towers) -> Towers
game ([], towers) = towers
game situation = game (move situation)
```

`situation` here has never mentioned in any part of the codes (there are a long code before this, called the tower of Hanoi, I suppose a lot of people here know it).
Why can we directly use `situation` here? I know this is correct and the code works very well, but I don't know why.

Comment: btw: I think this is the 3rd or 4th question on this in the last couple of days - is there a MOOC or something that has this as an exercise?

Comment: A rather trivial observation, move must extract elements from the list [Move] (perhaps according to some yet not all situations), in order to ensure the base case of empty list holds at some point, and thus ensure termination of the game.

Comment: yes. Carsten, we are having a class in LMU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`situation` is an argument to the function `game`.  It would have the type `([Move], Towers)`.  Essentially, what you're saying is "if `situation` has no moves then return the towers, otherwise perform a move and then pass that result to `game`".

It would be perfectly legal to write this function as

```
game ([], towers) = towers
game (moves, towers) = game (move (moves, towers))
```

But this requires taking apart a tuple then constructing a new one exactly like it, or you could use any other name for this value:

```
game ([], towers) = towers
game foobar = game (move foobar)
```

It's nothing more than a name for the argument to the function `game`, what it's actually called isn't important (so long as it's not a reserved keyword, of course, you couldn't name it `import`, for example).

Comment: @bheklilr "this requires taking apart a tuple then constructing a new one exactly like it" - Correct me if I'm wrong but this is something I would expect the compiler to optimise away.